# Unix tool to monitor too many open files?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a tool which can monitor whether a process is near limit of maximum open files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lsof -p process-id
```

From the man page

> Lsof  lists on its standard output file information about files opened by processes

[...]

```
       -p s     This option excludes or selects the listing of files  for  the
                processes  whose optional process IDentification (PID) numbers
                are  in  the  comma-separated  set  s  -  e.g.,   ``123''   or
                ``123,^456''.  (There should be no spaces in the set.)

                PID  numbers  that  begin with `^' (negation) represent exclu-
                sions.

                Multiple process ID numbers are joined in a  single  ORed  set
                before  participating  in  AND option selection.  However, PID
                exclusions are applied without ORing or ANDing and take effect
                before other selection criteria are applied.
```

[...]

```
       +|-r [t[m]]
                This option puts lsof in repeat mode.  There lsof  lists  open
                files  as selected by other options, delays t seconds (default
                fifteen), then  repeats  the  listing,  delaying  and  listing
                repetitively  until stopped by a condition defined by the pre-
                fix to the option.

                If the prefix is a `-', repeat mode is endless.  Lsof must  be
                terminated with an interrupt or quit signal.

                If  the prefix is `+', repeat mode will end the first cycle no
                open files are listed
```

Answer (score 0):

running this as root would give you the number of open files opened by the process with the most number of open files.  Because it does not actually follow the links in the proc tree, it moves a lot faster than lsof, and covers every running process on the box.  It does, however, need to be run as root.

```
find /proc/*/fd -type l -print | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1
```